# Scala: filter forcing evaluation of entire Stream

Tags: scala, filter, stream

The following code is called once from a method itself called once inside the Constructor of the class. When it gets executed as part of a specs UnitTest the Test gets stuck and a javaw process quickly consuming ever more memory is spawned.

```
private def placeMines( excludes: List[( Int, Int )] ) {
    def rndstream: Stream[( Int, Int )] = {
        def s: Stream[( Int, Int )] =
            ( Random.nextInt( ysize ), Random.nextInt(  xsize ) ) #:: s
        s
    }
    def posPermitted( pos: ( Int, Int ) ): Boolean = {
        !excludes.contains( pos ) &&
            fieldEmpty( pos._1, pos._2 )
    }
    val positions = rndstream.filter( posPermitted )
    positions.take( minecount ).foreach( x => grid( x._1 )( x._2 ) = MineField() )
}
```

In order to find out what's going on i have commented out the last line with the sideeffect (grid is a two dimensional array) and replaced the filter predicate with different ones, including x => false and x => true. Interestingly it terminates in the true case but keeps running forever with false. Inserting some printlns have showed the predicate is called hundred thousands of times before i terminate the java process.

I tried to reproduce the situation with the following code:

```
import scala.util.Random
import org.specs.SpecificationWithJUnit

class foobar extends SpecificationWithJUnit {
    val x = 0xDead
    val y = 0xBeef

    bar(x, y)

    private def bar(x: Int, y: Int) = foo(x)

    private def foo(x: Int) = {
        def s: Stream[( Int, Int )] = {
            def p: Stream[( Int, Int )] =
                ( Random.nextInt( x ), Random.nextInt( y ) ) #:: p
            p
        }
        val fiveodd = s.filter( x => x._1 % 2 == 1 )
        println( fiveodd.take( 5 ).toList )
    }
}
```

However that code runs just fine.

Searches for "scala stream filter endless" "scala stream filter forces evaluation" and "scala stream filter doesn't terminate" only brought up tutorials showcasing usages of stream which seemed in principle identical to my code.

Comment: by the way, it is possible to simplify the `rndstream` method: `def rndstream: Stream[( Int, Int )] = ( Random.nextInt( ysize ), Random.nextInt(  xsize ) ) #:: rndstream`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there is something wrong with your filter function. `Stream.filter` tries to find the first matching value and if there is none, it will search forever.

Take your example stream and call

```
s.filter(_ => false)
```

This will not return, so it has to be your filter function.

Comment: Well i checked again and while the predicate is responsible for the symptoms, the cause lies in the testcase and ysize and xsize. specifically i have a bunch of testcases using a 1 * 1 grid and in that case Random.next(*size) will obviously always return 0. But since i also have (0,0):: Nil specified as excludes the first part of the predicate always evaluates to false. I guess I'll make a change and demand ysize * xsize be at least 2 . I thank you for taking your time to answer me and apologize for wasting yours, when i should have questioned my predicate more from the start.